# Use concatenation to write the property name

Tags: php, object, variables, properties

There is a way to write this?

```
$request->inputModificaNome.$nomeModel.$i;
```

where "inputModificaNome" is always the same and $nomeModel and $i are variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using [Complex (curly) syntax:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

```
echo $request->{inputModificaNome.$nomeModel.$i};
```

Full example: https://eval.in/1045165

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$request->{sprintf("inputModificaNome%s%s",$nomeModel,$i)};
```

More detail : http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php